# Extend external .jar functionality with library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

**High level description:**  In Android Studio, I'd like to create/add a library that extends an external jar, but am confused about how to link the two in a project.

**Detailed Description:**  I'm using LibGDX for Android game development, which I can successfully include and use in AS.  I found [this](https://github.com/yangweigbh/Libgdx-CardBoard-Extension/tree/master/libgdx-cardboard) library which extends the LibGDX.jar functionality to interface with Google Cardboard, which is awesome!  I've found a couple of examples regarding adding new libraries to AS projects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio), but AS doesn't find a valid eclipse ADT/gradle project when I point to any of those folders.

What would be cool to know is how to create a library (with package name com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android) that extends the LibGDX.jar (which has the package com.badlogic.gdx).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to package the external jar into the library. This would be done by using [the oracle documentation on this.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html) Extract the external jar then update the library with the contents of it. After doing so you can import the combined library into Android studio.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  The LibGDX.jar is huge, as compared to this library that only has 4 classes.  I can see how this would get everything rolled together, although extracting the whole .jar just to add those few additional classes seems inefficient.